# Asychromous callback

Tags: javascript, php, callback

Ok, I've got it working but am a little unclear as to whether I have done it correctly.

I have the code:

```
function post(){
    var info = "hello";
    $.post("test.php", {"info":info}, function(data){
        if(data !== "success"){
            alert("Test failed");
        }
        else{
            doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

php looks like this:

```
<?php

$info = $_POST['info'];
$data = failed;

if(isset($_POST['info'])){
    $data = "success";
}

echo $data;

?>
```

It works at the moment, but would this ajax call be asynchronous? does it involve a callback? Should I be handling it another way?

Comment: The anonymous function in `$.post()`'s arguments _is_ callback.

Comment: So the doSomething() function already acts as a callback.

Comment: sir, your code is correct, congrats

Comment: ok, thanks for that.

Comment: Only thing left to check is what triggers the function?

Comment: please check out the comment I left on the correct answer, I could really do with an answer to the question I asked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would this ajax call be asynchronous

Yes; [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is shorthand for [JQuery's `$.ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which by default is asynchronous.

> does it involve a callback

Of course, your function at the end of this statement *is* the callback function.

```
$.post("test.php", {"info":info}, function(data){
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if(data !== "success"){
        alert("Test failed");
    }
    else{
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

You can read more about the API and how these functions work, what are their default values, and what kind of parameters they accept:

- [JQuery post method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [JQuery ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: ok, I have another question. I think my problem is that on a previous function I had multiple post requests and so data wasn't being assigned for use in following post requests. How does a browser handle multiple post requests in on function? Does it make a call and then continue to execute following code?

Comment: @TomAlbanese Maybe try making this into a separate question so people can have a fuller understanding of your issue

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods would make it easier to follow.

```
function post() {
    return $.post("test.php", {info:"hello"}).done(function () {
        doSomething();
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("Test failed");
    });
}
```

And then in the PHP code you have to indicate when the request failed:

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['info'])) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 400 Bad Request');
    die;
}
// Do what you need to do...
```

When you call `$.post` (or `$.get` and `$.ajax`) you get back a *deferred value*. Deferred values are things that will finish (or fail) in the future.

In order to find out when the deferred value is done you can add callback handlers to the deferred value using `.done(fn)` and `.fail(fn)`. When the deferred value is done the callback functions will be called.

Comment: @NaN I don't know. You tell me. I find it to be much cleaner. If the server cannot handle the request then it fails. Simple. Determining if a request failed based on the data that it returns just complicates something that should be simple.